# Drupal - How to use Computed field in field collection item fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-computed-field

I have custom content type type_a

Inside that custom type I have few titles
Title 
Body 
Group1 (field_group1) (Field Collection Item Can have multiple values)

Following are the details of fields inside Group1 (Field Collection Item)
Group Item 1 (field_item1) Can have one value
Group Item 2 (field_item2) (Computed field) Can have one value

I would like to copy value of "Group Item 1" field of same field collection item inside "Group Item 2"

Below is I am using in computed code:
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_item1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

But it is not working. I am getting an error 
Notice: Undefined index: value in eval() (line 1 of /homepages/13/d160804/htdocs/test/sites/all/modules/computed_field/computed_field.module(466) : eval()'d code).

Please help how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$entity->field_item1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` contains the entity id of the field collection item (which contains the fields you want to copy).

You either need to load both field collection items and set their individual fields. Eg,

```
$source_fc = field_collection_item_load($entity->field_item1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
$dest_fc = field_collection_item_load($entity->field_item2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);

// now set values of $dest_fc with values from $source_fc
```

Or do some sort of clone similar to this method: http://drupal.org/node/1233256#comment-5167316